# Geopandas not returning correct buffer in meters

Tags: python, buffer, gis, geopandas

I have a linestring geometry of which I want to calculate the corresponding buffer of 1 km in width. Despite setting the CRS i don't seem to be able to return the correct geometry

I'm running the following code to define  the geodataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely import LineString
import geopandas as gpd

test = pd.DataFrame(
    [["Test", LineString([(41.000, 18.583), (40.892, 18.952)])]], 
    columns=["Nome", "geometry"]
    )

test = gpd.GeoDataFrame(test, crs='EPSG:3003', geometry="geometry")
```

the crs is correctly set up and is in meters

```
>>> test.crs

<Projected CRS: EPSG:3003>
Name: Monte Mario / Italy zone 1
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- X[east]: Easting (metre)
- Y[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: Italy - onshore and offshore - west of 12°E.
- bounds: (5.93, 36.53, 12.0, 47.04)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: Italy zone 1
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: Monte Mario
- Ellipsoid: International 1924
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

however when i try to calculate the buffer i get this

```
>>> test.buffer(1000)

POLYGON ((-918.845 -261.947, -941.757 -166.523...
```

[Buffer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgkuS.png)

as you can see the buffer is clearly wrong as the coordinates are not even valid coordinates (lat is -918.845!)
what am I doing wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're treating [EPSG:3003](https://epsg.io/3003) as a geographic CRS. Since your input is in *lat/lon*, you should initialize the [`GeoDataFrame`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/geodataframe.html) with [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326), then use [`to_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) before making the [`buffer`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.buffer.html) :

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(test, geometry="geometry", crs=4326).to_crs(3003)

print(gdf.buffer(1000).to_crs(4326))

# 0    POLYGON ((40.88408 18.94991, 40.88390 18.95066...
# dtype: geometry
```

Output :

```
ax = gdf.to_crs(4326).plot(color="r")

gdf.buffer(1000).to_crs(4326).plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]